# Asp.Net MVC - Refresher Course

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

When MVC first came out, I was reading about it everyday and learning all I could about it. About the time MVC 2 RC2 came out, I stopped learning for various reasons (new house, new job, laziness).

I now want to get back into MVC ... I have a half written blog that I want to finish, but I feel rusty when it comes to anything MVC.  Can anyone provide me some good links to refresher courses on MVC?  I don't need to learn from scratch, but I want to refresh, then learn about changes from MVC 2 RC2 to MVC 3.

EDIT:  Anyone know an ETA on when MVC 3 is going to release?  Should I convert my current MVC 2 project to MVC 3 ... or wait for an RC ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always hit the ASP.NET MVC site

http://www.asp.net/mvc

I dunno about you but I do better just looking at and writing code to figure things out.  Jon Galloway has put up the MVC Music Store, I believe this has been updated for MVC 2

http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/

Also the Nerd Dinner code has been updated for MVC 2 as well

http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/releases/view/45647

Finally Phil Haack has the updates to MVC 2 on his blog which has a number of links to tell you what has changed from 1 to 2. This post is probably the most valuable information if you just want to know what has changed from 1 to 2.

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/03/11/aspnet-mvc2-released.aspx

As the last couple of posters mentioned, Scott Gu has a good post on MVC 3 Preview 1 Features, and Phil Haack also has a post on his blog.

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/27/aspnetmvc3-preview1-released.aspx

Comment: Don't bother with that nerddinner app. I didn't find it very helpful and the book he wrote explaining how to build it was wrought with errors that prevented it from even compiling. Check out this book from apress, a brilliant and smooth read: http://www.apress.com/book/view/1430228865

Answer (score 2):

Pick up the book "[MVC2 in Action](http://www.manning.com/palermo2/)" from Manning and take a look at the latest [MVCConf videos](http://www.viddler.com/explore/mvcconf/videos/). I found the one done by Jimmy Bogard enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

Read and try ["Nerd Dinner"](http://aspnetmvcbook.s3.amazonaws.com/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v1.pdf).  I used it when I first started doing ASP.NET MVC2 2 months ago, and it helped a lot.  (Right click the link and Save Target As.  It's a PDF by Wrox)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a good page on [ASP.NET MVC 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394709.aspx), which has tutorials covering most important aspects of the framework, as well as several references to blog posts going into things in more detail. That would seem a pretty natural place to start.

For MVC 3 the best resource currently seems to be [Scott Gu's introductory blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx).