# What is ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC, and plan on using it for an upcoming project. I have some questions:

1. I don't know what type of database the project is using. It might be SQL Server or a mySQL database. If I use LINQ to SQL, can I switch databases on demand?
2. Do people still use LINQ to SQL?
3. I need a membership provider. In ASP.NET Microsoft provided a tool for create the membership tables and data. Is it still the same for MVC? (We also might use Live ID, or OpenID, or Facebook Connect, is it possible to integrate in the future?)
4. What is ASP.NET MVC 2?
5. Whats the best way to get started on  ASP.NET MVC 2? I have Visual Studio 2010.
6. Is there a relationship between WPF and ASP.NET MVC 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unnumbered Question) Use MVC 2, it is newer, so more features.

1) No - Linq To Sql only supports Sql Server.

2) Yes.  I use it a lot, mostly for all of my small projects I want to get up and running quickly.

3) MVC uses the same Membership as Asp.Net (since MVC is built on Asp.Net)

4) [What's new in MVC2](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/what-is-new-in-aspnet-mvc)

5) Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522555/asp-net-mvc-refresher-course) I asked.

6) There is no relationship.

**EDIT:**  [Entity Framework and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488/using-mysql-with-entity-framework) - [Entity Framework and Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82644/can-you-use-microsoft-entity-framework-with-oracle)

Comment: What ORM can I use to make sure its compatible with the few popular ones out there.

Comment: @masfenix - See my edit for using Entity Framework with MySQL and Oracle.

Comment: @masfenix - That comes built in.  You should be able to connect to Sql Server and drop the tables on (just like Linq to Sql)

Comment: Entity Framework is so awesome. I'm using it with everything now. I find it to be just as simple to use as LINQ to SQL and it supports MANY data sources! I think EF is a beautiful thing :)

Answer (score 4):

Regarding question number 5, the best thing you can do is get yourself a copy of Steven Sanderson's Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework.

[http://www.amazon.com/ASP-NET-Framework-Second-Experts-Voice/dp/1430228865](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430228865)

Answer (score 2):

You should defenitely use MVC version 2, since that is the latest one. I would actually choose version 3 if I was to start at new website now, since the release candidate has been released, so the final version should be imminent.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3

Comment: No, this only answers the question about what version to use. :) I personally think that you should keep it to one question and one answer per entry, so that the voting system can be used to distinguish the good from the bad.

Answer (score 2):

> I am thinking of doing it in MVC1/2 (which is better?).

The version 1 is obsolete. Version 2 is the latest official release. As you're just starting now i would recommend using the version 3.

1) No. linq2sql just support sql server

2) I've never used in my life.

3) Yes .is still the same. Except some slightly changes in configuring it, you can go straight with your knowledge

4) This is a very large question. MVC is an architectural pattern. ASP.NET MVC is the microsoft implementation of that pattern

5) http://www.asp.net/mvc

6) NO

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC 3RC has just released.

5: [This](http://content.wrox.com/wroxfiles/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v2.pdf) builds a complete ASP.NET MVC reference application step by step. Maybe you can begin to know ASP.NET MVC from here. It's based on version 2.

Answer (score 0):

Peopl seem to have cover the basics of your question but a good resource to get you started would be :

[Channel 9 Full Stack Series](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/The-Full-Stack)

This is a walk through of some of the new MVC 3 features including EF nuGet(Pack) and even soem win phone 7 stuff.

Also Scott Hanselmans talk at PDC is pretty good but again is based on MVC 3

[Scott's talk PDC 10](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PDC10BuildingABlogWithMicrosoftUnnamedPackageOfWebLove.aspx)

I'd recommend looking into 3 it has some nice features and is RC Release Candidate now, So wont be to long before it's full release.  Would be a shame to get your app up and running just when you need to update to get all the new goodies ;)

Also agree with Hector [Steve Sandersons book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/ASP-NET-Framework-Experts-Voice-NET/dp/1430228865/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1289815196&sr=1-1) on MVC is a great read covers everything you need (and is V2)